# How to count the number of words in a string? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

Hey guys I need some help. What expression do I use to count the number of words in a user-inputted string in Visual Basic? It needs to be done without making it an array.

Comment: `It needs to be done without making it an array.` So even not temporary with `.Split(...)` ?

Comment: do it using sting length keword....

Comment: If you cannot use an array, you'll need to loop through all of the characters in the string from beginning to end and keep count of each time you encounter a word break.  Give it a shot and let us know if you run into any problems.

Comment: @LawranceRozario length on a string counts characters, OP wants words

Comment: @Skindeep2366 Errrrm i think you going to need a + 1 for the correct answer here. Length on its own will not work is why i commented

Comment: @Conor oh common dude What you waiting for ? Just tell us your response if none of our answer work so we suggest better or else you accept the right answer

Answer (score 3):

```
Public Function CountWords(ByVal value As String) As Integer

' Count matches.
Dim collection As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(value, "\S+")
Return collection.Count

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim testString = "this is a test string with 8 words."
Dim counter = 1
For Each testCharacter In testString 
   If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testCharacter)) Then
      counter += 1
   End If
Next
```

Comment: This is a good example, though it does have some technical problems (e.g. counting 1 for an empty string, double counting two consecutive spaces), but answering such questions ought to be frowned upon.  It's clearly a school-work question, so simply providing a working example without any further explanation does little to help the student learn anything.

Comment: The answer was based off the test string and did not cater for null strings, carriage returns, double spaces etc. I understand what you are saying though, but this example could have countless other factors to cater for. This is just a basic answer to a basic question and anything more complex would have confused OP