# Count a Item Integer in a Multi-Line Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to play a little with the Textbox. how do I count the items of a textbox? Example: The first line contains the characters: 12 14 16 18 so there are 4 characters but i have one code, and show me 8 character, not 4. how do I display this Count in another textbox? So how do all the characters look into? limited space or comma.

```
secondTextBox.Text = firstTextBox.Text.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).Count()
```

this code takes every single digit, I want to take it as a integer. i.e. 12, 14, 16, 18, as a integer.

Comment: A cheating kind of way I suppose would be just count the spaces. However many " " there is usually means how many characters before it there is.
e.g
textbox = 55 88 77 5 99 22
`Dim space_count() As String = Split(TextBox1.Text, " ")`
space_count() = 6

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim number As Integer
secondTextBox.Text = firstTextBox.Text.Split(", ".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(Function(x) Integer.TryParse(x, number)).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways of doing this, but the simplest which doesn't take account of humans would depend on two things

If all the numbers are on one line and just contain one space between the numbers and no spaces after the last number, just count the number of spaces

To do this in your code you would write

```
secondTextBox.Text = (firstTextBox.Text.Where(Function(x) Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).Count() + 1).ToString
```

If the numbers are on separate lines with no blank lines inbetween the numbers or before or after the numbers, then you would use

```
secondTextBox.Text = firstTextBox.Lines.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to text searches it may help to take a look at RegEx (Regular Expressions). From your question, it seems you want to count the number of words in a user input. If so, [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376198/how-to-count-the-number-of-words-in-a-string-vb-net) and its first answer.